# Getting error while the installation of geopandas, Cartopy, Proj?

Tags: python

When I am trying to install Cartopy keep getting below error:

> ```
> C:\Users\Justin\Documents\Python Programs>pip install cartopy Collecting cartopy   Using cached
> ```

```
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/92/fe8838fa8158931906dfc4f16c5c1436b3dd2daf83592645b179581403ad/Cartopy-0.17.0.tar.gz
> Installing build dependencies ... done
>     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>     C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cetb0vj7\cartopy\setup.py:171:
> UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.3.3
> or later installed, or installation may fail.
>       '.'.join(str(v) for v in GEOS_MIN_VERSION), ))
>     Proj 4.9.0 must be installed.
> 
>     ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cetb0vj7\cartopy\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try executing these line by line in the terminal window instead of downloading the `.whl` file externally. Moreover, earlier I tried with external source, and due to that mass up happend. Hence, I would recommend to go with `pipwin install`.

```
pip install wheel
pip install pipwin
pipwin install numpy
pipwin install pandas
pipwin install shapely
pipwin install gdal
pipwin install fiona
pipwin install pyproj
pipwin install six
pipwin install rtree    
pipwin install geopandas
```